# Conflits between namespace and library

Tags: c#, dll, conflict

I'm using a namespace `ListExtensionsMethods`(defined in file  `ext.cs`) both in my C# `dl.dll` and in the `main.cs` file. But when I try to include `dl.dll`  in the `main.cs` I get about 30 error messages like this:

> Warning   2    The type 'ListExtensionsMethods.MachineExtensions' in
>   'b:\library\C#\ext.cs' conflicts with the imported type
>   'ListExtensionsMethods.MachineExtensions' in 'C:\path\update.dll'.
>   Using the type defined in
>   'b:\library\C#\ext.cs'.   C:\path\db.cs   52  39  testing

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's in `C:\path\update.dll`?

Comment: the library I've created. That library uses `ext.cs` file too.

Comment: Why not just use the functions from the library, instead of copying the entire .cs file into the application?

Comment: @BenVoigt: By copying did you the `ext.cs` file I did included in `main.cs`? I do use different functions from `ext.cs` in the `main.cs` file and in the library. I included the library in `main.cs` to use functions of the library (obviously).

Comment: @Jack: If `ext.cs` is in the library, then *all* of its functions are in the library, and `main.cs` can use them also.  Not just functions which the library uses.

Comment: If you are going to include the same file in multiple assemblies consider declaring the types in it internal so other assemblies won't see it, especially if it is just a few utility extension methods.

Comment: @mikez: I still didn't understand well how this is giving conflitcs  because to me it's same as a `foo.dll` which include `System.IO` and my `main.cs` include `foo.dll` and `System.IO`. This is very common. Don't know what I'm missing. I'll check out about `internal` and seems if it does solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: @BenVoigt: I understand it more or less. It's same as do a C's #include "foo.h" in two files without include guard, isn't? if so, how do I do a "include guard" in c#?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I understand it more or less. It's same as do a C's #include "foo.h" in two files without include guard, isn't? if so, how do I do a "include guard" in c#?

Comment: @Jack No its not the same because foo uses the assembly containing System.IO not the actual file. It sounds like you should just remove ext.cs from main.

Comment: @mikez: I guess removing it will works. I'm going give a try. But how could I include `ext.cs` where I use functions from it without those conflicts?

Comment: @Jack: `internal` should work as well.  Use it on the classes not the member functions.

Comment: @Jack There are two reasonable options. 1) Whatever is in ext.cs is in sync with the scope of foo.dll and should be exposed publicly by it. Then, ext.cs is included only in foo.dll and main references foo.dll. Main does not include ext.cs. It just uses the namespace out of foo.dll 2) ext.cs is really just some utility code that is needed by both main and foo but is not within the scope of foo. The file ext.cs should then only contain internal classes and it can be included in both projects. The other option is to define an assembly alias which is not reasonable for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use the [global namespace](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/global-namespace-in-c), however this warning exists for a reason and you should make sure you really want to use the same namespacing.